# Revolution slider images not showing after plugin update

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, revolution-slider

On one of my WordPress websites, the revolution slider was working fine but after I updated the plugin the slider is not showing images. I have previewed the slider in the revolution slider section(admin side) and it is showing images and working fine but on the home page, it is not showing images. I have checked in firebug and there is only one error but that doesn't seem to be the problem because after that I have added the layer slider and it is working fine with that also files(revolution slider) are added correctly but I am unable to locate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to figure it out by myself and basically it was conflict of js files of revolution slider with the date-time picker plugin. so i ended up remove datetime picker plugin because I don't really need it much and after that it works. So for you who are reading this you need to check the conflict between the js files you have added and to resolve the conflict initially just change the order of js file.